# Mod Rewrite + QSA : Same querystring param in rewrite target and in querystring - Force use of target possible?

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

We have the following rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?rewrite=$1 [L,QSA]
```

We were wondering if there was a way to have the ?rewrite=$1 take precedence over one that is passed via the query string in the request uri?

Because as it stands now, due to the **QSA flag** (which we do need btw) if the following url is hit:

```
 http://www.domain.com/this_rewrite_will_match_the_above_rule?rewrite=some_value
```

The value of $_GET['rewrite'] in PHP will be **some_value**, and not **this_rewrite_will_match_the_above rule**.

Before we go in and start modifying the rewrites and adding a RewriteCond to match the query string, etc etc... We were hoping there was a flag to set so that the target url (index.php?rewrite=$1 in this case) took precedence over the passed query string values.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opted to create an answer of my own, because its slightly cleaner then the examples provided by Jpsy and Gerben.

Credit where credit is due, their suggestions are what got me here, I only expanded on them:

So, our final solution includes 2 rules.

```
# check if querystring is not empty (this is the addition vs other answers)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&rewrite=$1 [L]
```

if the above query string fails (mainly, the querystring is empty) this rule will apply.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?rewrite=$1 [L]
```

The reason I opted to go for this dual rule setup is to avoid having the php server variables polluted with "?&rewrite=...." if the query string is empty.

Thanks to jpsy and gerben for the help.

Comment: Yes, the solutions of me and Gerben (definitely more elegant and faster than mine!) create a "?&" sequence when the querystring is empty. But this sequence is just ignored. I basically would not add another condition to avoid that. Keep in mind that this additional condition is checked for each and every file that is requested from the server (HTML, images, CSS and JS files, ...). An alternative would be to put the condition **after** the -d and -f checks, so it is skipped for all existing files and dirs.

Comment: I agree. The sequence is ignored. The main reason I opted to avoid this ?& is because the codebase is about 3-4 years old, rather large and I am unsure if there are any spots where the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] variable is pattern matched / split / etc etc... Just being safe. But, in any other case I would go with Gerben's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly hackish

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&rewrite=$1 [L]
```

This works because, in php, the second `rewrite=...` overwrite the first.

Answer (score 2):

I have searched for some mechanics to override single querystring parameters in an Apache rewrite multiple times and quite intensely, but it looks like there is no option to do that, even with the latest Apache version (2.4.3 at the time of this writing).

But there is an alternative that makes use of the fact that the PHP querystring parser only returns the last of multiple idententical querystring parameters.

Example:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=123&id=456
```

This will return the following single (!) entry in $_GET:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "456"
}
```

So you can solve your problem by simply **appending** any override parameters to the end of your existing querystring (without removing them within the querystring). The last occurrence of a repeated parameter is the one that makes it into the $_GET array.

Unfortunately the QSA switch is not suitable for this technique, as it always appends the original parameters to the end of the new querystring. There is no switch that would preprend the old parameters. So you have to take a little detour with a RewriteCond to catch and prepend the original querystring yourself instead of using QSA:

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?%1&rewrite=$1 [L]
```

The only function of the RewriteCond is to capture the querystring in %1. The regexp `(.*)` of the condition is always matched, so the following RewriteRule is always executed.

With this technique your above testcase will rewrite to...

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?rewrite=some_value&rewrite=this_rewrite_will_match_the_above_rule
```

...which will be interpreted by the PHP querystring parser to

```
$_GET["id"] => "this_rewrite_will_match_the_above_rule"
```

...which is what you want.

Please be aware that this will work only if you take your querystring values from PHP's $_GET array. It will not necessarily work if you parse the content of `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` yourself or if you use any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following instructions:

```
RewriteRule ([^\?]*)\?(.*) $1?$2 [N]                          (1)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)&?(rewrite=[^&]+)&?(.*)      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&%3 [N]                               (2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?domain=newValue [L,QSA]                 (3)
```

The trick is done by the [N] flag in the first two rules, which causes to rewrite engine to re-process the output.

Rule (1) simple rewrites the url as it is. I needed it because I'm using mod_rewrite togheter with mod_proxy_ajp and in the first iteration the query string is not splitted from the url. After the execution of the first line, the url is unchanged but the engine will split the path from the query string.

Rule (2) iterates and removes all occurrences of the parameter "rewrite" from the query string.

Rule (3) sets the new value for the parameter and appends whichever query string survives from the replacement done by rule (2).